# Is there a way to reduce by partition in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

Does apache beam allow for reduce operation per partition ?

For more context, I am looking to understand if it is possible in apache beam to aggregate the data in the partition before shuffling the data to one node for final merge of aggregates?

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean by partition, can you clarify? Have you looked at GroupByKey and Combine in Beam SDK? If your elements have some sort of a natural key, then GroupByKey would pile the elements with the same key (on the same machine), and then you can send the result of the GBK (it will be a collection of elements with the same key) to a ParDo to do the aggregation.

Comment: For some aggregations you may achieve the same effect using Combine, which will be more efficient but CombineFns have extra requirements: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine . If you have multiple steps in this process you might need to manually re-key and combine the elements again.

Comment: You can also split a PCollection into multiple PCollections using a Partition transform, and then use CoGroupByKey, not sure if this fits your use case

Comment: I am trying to see if i can run local aggregation on the split before invoking a shuffle with GroupByKey

Answer (score 0):

With some guessing, if I understand your question correctly, doing this means 1) doing a limited-scope (i.e. per partition/shard) shuffle first, reduce, and then 2) shuffle cross/between different partitions then reduce again.

In most case, doing this won't benefit unless doing a step 1) reduce significantly reduce the amount of data-transmission needed for step 2) shuffle above. And if that is the case, consider using a "combine". Under the hood, a combine does (almost) the same to what you propose.